# What is Rack endpoint?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack

When you do:

```
run SomeClass.new
```

in Rack, `SomeClass.new` is called a Rack "endpoint". I know that usually an endpoint is: The endpoint is the URL where your service can be accessed by a client application. How does this apply to Rack and why is the argument to `run` called an "endpoint"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [Rack](http://rack.github.io/) is a modular web server abstraction
>   layer that unifies the API for the interaction of Ruby web application
>   frameworks and application servers. It
>   [specifies](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/SPEC.html) a simple
>   interface for Rack-compliant applications, and defines standard
>   request and response objects and application server adapters to
>   abstract dealing with the low level details of serving web requests. ***A
>   Rack endpoint is just an application that adheres to the Rack spec***.

[Reference](http://library.edgecase.com/rails-routing-and-rack-endpoints).